# How can I define my own InputFilter and allow for only certain types (see post) of input?

Tags: android, android-edittext, input-filtering

Let's say I have an EditText and I want to restrict it to 0-9 and A-F (inclusive), for hex input. Is there a way I can do that? I tried looking at InputFilters and I'm not sure that's the right way. Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the input type to number and digits to "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
In an xml file it would look like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/hexedit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    android:inputType="number"      
/>
```

You can experiment with different inputTypes to see which soft keyboard layout they bring up.

Comment: Thanks. This actually works! But.......I don't like the way it looks. I think for my usage, I'm better off making a custom keyboard out of buttons. Thanks though.